# How to remove every second string of each tuple, that is inside a tuple, inside a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following code (is working code):

```
import csv

original_list = [('1321', '01'), ('MessageXZY', '02'), ('DescriptionSKS', '03'), ('S7_6', '04'), ('S7_3', '05'), ('0A3B', '06'), ('MessageZYA', '07'), ('DescriptionKAM', '08'), ('9K44', '09'), ('MessageYAL', '10'),
 ('DescriptionAUS', '11'), ('S7_2', '12')]

code_list = ['1321', '0A3B','9K44']

grouped_tuples = []
for entry in original_list:
    if entry[0] in code_list:
        new_tuple = []
        new_tuple.append(entry)
        for i in range(original_list.index(entry)+1, len(original_list)):
            if(original_list[i][0] not in code_list):
                new_tuple.append(original_list[i])
            else:
                break
        grouped_tuples.append(tuple(new_tuple))
```

If I then add on:

```
for entry in grouped_tuples:
    for item in entry:
        print (item[1])
```

I get the following list:

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

What I want to do is remove these numbers from the tuples. So instead of using the above code, I used:

```
for entry in grouped_tuples:
    for item in entry:
        a = grouped_tuples.remove(item[1])
print (a)
```

However I get the message: **ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list** I know that item[0] is in the list as I just printed it. What is causing this error?

Comment: Tuples are immutable, you can't remove items from them - you have to create a new tuple without that item.

Comment: your list includes tuples of tuples

Answer (score 3):

You do not necessarily need to `remove` the elements, you can create a new tuple on the fly with the desired values as:

```
>>> new_list = [(i[0],)for i in original_list]
>>> [('1321',), ('MessageXZY',), ('DescriptionSKS',), ('S7_6',), ('S7_3',), ('0A3B',), ('MessageZYA',), ('DescriptionKAM',), ('9K44',), ('MessageYAL',), ('DescriptionAUS',), ('S7_2',)]
```

Comment: You also probably don't need to create a 1-element tuple. Simply return `i[0]` instead of `(i[0],)`

Comment: @EricDuminil Never know if OP wants the data to be in a specific format for further processing.

Comment: I'd be curious to see any practical application for a 1-element tuple in Python. Since tuples are immutable, there's really not much you can do expect call `[0]` on it.

Comment: Yes I completely agree on this stance But Don't assume that this list of tuples has the aim of just storing some values, what if the OP is going to create a `numpy` matrix or `xyz` object, which requires the list in a specific format, then `[(1, ), (2, ) .. ]` would not be same as `[1, 2 ...]`

Comment: Yes I am actually trying to remove the second string of the tuple and convert the whole thing to a string

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt seems pretty convoluted to me. Unless I have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve, a one liner should be sufficient.

`[(k,) for (k,v) in original_list if k in code_list]`

Answer (score 0):

To get the first element of tuples within a list, one solution could be:

For each tuple in the list:

1. Convert the tuple to a list `a`
2. Store first element from `a` as a single element in list `b`
   tuple

E.g.:

```
>>> a=[("x","z"),("y","z")]
>>> b=[(list(x)[0],) for x in a]
>>> b
[('x',), ('y',)]
```

Using this concept with your code gives:

```
>>> grouped_tuples
[(('1321', '01'), ('MessageXZY', '02'), ('DescriptionSKS', '03'), ('S7_6', '04'), ('S7_3', '05')), (('0A3B', '06'), ('MessageZYA', '07'), ('DescriptionKAM', '08')), (('9K44', '09'), ('Messag
eYAL', '10'), ('DescriptionAUS', '11'), ('S7_2', '12'))]
>>> #preserve grouped_tuples
... tmpGroupedTuples=list(grouped_tuples)
>>> tmpGroupedTuples_len=len(tmpGroupedTuples)
>>> for i in range(0,tmpGroupedTuples_len):
...     cOuterTuple=list(tmpGroupedTuples[i])
...     cOuterTupleLen=len(cOuterTuple)
...     newOuterTuple=[]
...     for j in range(0,cOuterTupleLen):
...             cInnerTuple=list(cOuterTuple[j])
...             newInnerTuple=((cInnerTuple[0],))
...             newOuterTuple.append(newInnerTuple)
...     tmpGroupedTuples[i]=tuple(newOuterTuple)
...
```

`tmp_grouped_tuples` now contains outer tuples containing inner tuples that contain the first element of the original inner tuples of `grouped_tuples`:

```
>>> print(tmpGroupedTuples)
[(('1321',), ('MessageXZY',), ('DescriptionSKS',), ('S7_6',), ('S7_3',)), (('0A3B',), ('MessageZYA',), ('DescriptionKAM',)), (('9K44',), ('MessageYAL',), ('DescriptionAUS',), ('S7_2',))]
```